# Number() when used on a string returns Nan

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, rest, parseint

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
app.put("/transaction/:value/:id1/:id2", async(req,res) => {
    try {
        const {value,id1,id2} = req.params;

        const bal1 = await pool.query("Select balance from balance where id=$1",[id1]);
        const bal2 = await pool.query("Select balance from balance where id=$1",[id2]);

        const ball1 = JSON.stringify(bal1.rows[0].balance);
        const ball2 = JSON.stringify(bal2.rows[0].balance);
        const convball1 = Number(ball1);
        
        console.log(convball1);
```

This is a PERN project I'm trying working on and I need the convball1 value as int to further test conditions but I am not able to use it as int.

When the bal1 value was retrieved from the database, it came out as like this: `[{"balance":"50"}]` which is why the sanitizing at ball1. But the value at ball1 shows up as `"50"`.

**Need ball1 has an integer**

***Update:***
I did as mentioned used parseInt() instead of Number(), but I got the same error. So, I checked the MDN web docs for the parseInt() funtion and they mention using another argument called radix.

So, a radix of 10 will convert decimal numbers to int format, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.
***Getting the same error***

Comment: use parseInt instead of Number for this case.

Comment: Why are you stringifying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned you get `[{"balance":"50"}]` as your output;

When I do `[{"balance":"50"}][0].balance` I will get "50" and `Number("50")` will give me 50.

You are doing   `JSON.stringify([{"balance":"50"}][0].balance)` will result in ""50"" and Number(""50"") will be `Nan`

Avoid `JSON.stringify` and you would be good.

Answer (score 0):

use + sign thats it, To convert string to number

```
const convball1 = +ball1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is coming out as JSON, so my advice is to parse it to an object using JSON.parse().

Here's an example:

```
const ball1 = JSON.parse('[{"balance":"50"}]');
console.log(parseInt(ball1[0].balance));
```

The reason your method won't work is because you try to parse an invalid number using Number(), it's invalid because it has alphabetical and specical characters like "balance" and "[]" characters included in the string, so of course it will return NaN.